# Pandas Rounds int64 number when loading dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am loading a list of dictionaries into a pandas dataframe, i.e. if d is my list of dicts, simply:

`pd.DataFrame(d)`

Unfortunately, one value in the dictionary is a 64-bit integer. It is getting converted to float because some dictionaries don't have a value for this column and are therefore given `NaN` values, thereby converting the entire column to a float.

For example:

```
                col1
0       NaN
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       0.000000e+00
4       1.506758e+18
5       1.508758e+18
```

If I try to `fillna` all the `NaN`s to zero then recast the column `astype(np.int64)` returns values that are all slightly off (due to rounding). How can I avoid this and keep my original 64-bit values intact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo:

```
In [10]: d
Out[10]: {'a': [1506758000000000000, nan, 1508758000000000000]}
```

Naive approach:

```
In [11]: pd.DataFrame(d)
Out[11]:
              a
0  1.506758e+18
1           NaN
2  1.508758e+18
```

Workaround (pay attention at `dtype=str`):

```
In [12]: pd.DataFrame(d, dtype=str).fillna(0).astype(np.int64)
Out[12]:
                     a
0  1506758000000000000
1                    0
2  1508758000000000000
```

Comment: I like it.  Great use of `dtype` in the constructor.

Comment: Why not just `pd.DataFrame(d,dtype=np.int64)` ?

Comment: Thanks.  pd.DataFrame(d,dtype=np.int64).fillna(0) seems to do the same job and is faster.

Comment: @B.M., please turn your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no way to override the inference here, you will need to fill the missing values before passing to `pandas`.  Something like this:

```
d = [{'col1': 1}, {'col2': 2}]

cols_to_check = ['col1']

for row in d:
    for col in cols_to_check:
        if col not in row:
            row[col] = 0

d
Out[39]: [{'col1': 1}, {'col1': 0, 'col2': 2}]

pd.DataFrame(d)
Out[40]: 
   col1  col2
0     1   NaN
1     0   2.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid this was the only way.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a series with comprehension and unstack with a `fill_value` parameter

```
pd.Series(
    {(i, j): v for i, x in enumerate(d)
              for j, v in x.items()},
    dtype=np.int64
).unstack(fill_value=0)
```